# Where can I find an RSS feed for TRULY “big deal” news headlines?

Tags: webapp-rec

Most news feeds give all their main headlines for the day, but is there a feed that only gives the headlines that are actually really important?

For example, the death of a public figure, major political developments, natural disasters. The kind of headlines that happen once or twice a month.